# Use SQL Server Agent to schedule a job

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, schedule, sql-server-agent

I wrote a stored procedure and I need to schedule it to run monthly.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2015. In that Object Explorer it doesn't have SQL Server Agent. Anyone know about this and if it is not possible how to schedule stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio 2015.

Comment: If it is express edition then you do not have sql server agent option. So you can use windows scheduler on that workstation where sql server installed. Please check this link. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50257

Comment: SSMS is just a client interface to SQL Server and as such isn't the same version as the database engine. To get the version number of interest try `select @@version`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not granted the needed permissions, you will not be able to see the Agent, no matter whether you run Enterprise/Standard/Datacenter, etc...

The roles needed are sysadmin, or the individual roles here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx